# Unit testing ASP.Net MVC Authorize attribute to verify redirect to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is probably going to turn out to be a case of just needing another pair of eyes. I must be missing something, but I cannot figure out why this kind of thing cannot be tested for. I'm basically trying to ensure that unauthenticated users cannot access the view by marking the controller with the [Authorize] attribute and I'm trying to tests this using the following code:

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldRedirectToLoginForUnauthenticatedUsers()
{
    var mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>()
                         { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
    var controller = new MyAdminController() 
              {ControllerContext = mockControllerContext.Object};
    mockControllerContext.Setup(c =>
               c.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(false);
    var result = controller.Index();
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<RedirectResult>(result);
}
```

The RedirectResult I'm looking for is some kind of indication that the user is being redirected to the login form, but instead a ViewResult is always returned and when debugging I can see that the Index() method is successfully hit even though the user is not authenticated.

Am I doing something wrong? Testing at the wrong level? Should I rather be testing at the route level for this kind of thing?

I know that the [Authorize] attribute is working, because when I spin up the page, the login screen is indeed forced upon me - but how do I verify this in a test?

The controller and index method are very simple just so that I can verify the behaviour. I've included them for completeness:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyAdminController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: One way to test this is to use integration testing using in memory host server provided by Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing, in which you can mock AuthHandler.
details can be found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You are testing at the wrong level. The [Authorize] attribute ensures that the *routing* engine will never invoke that method for an unauthorized user - the RedirectResult will actually be coming from the route, not from your controller method.

Good news is - there's already test coverage for this (as part of the MVC framework source code), so I'd say you don't need to worry about it; just make sure your controller method does the right thing *when* it gets called, and trust the framework not to call it in the wrong circumstances.

EDIT: If you want to verify the presence of the attribute in your unit tests, you'll need to use reflection to inspect your controller methods as follows. This example will verify the presence of the Authorize attribute on the ChangePassword POST method in the 'New ASP.NET MVC 2 Project' demo that's installed with MVC2.

```
[TestFixture]
public class AccountControllerTests {

    [Test]
    public void Verify_ChangePassword_Method_Is_Decorated_With_Authorize_Attribute() {
        var controller = new AccountController();
        var type = controller.GetType();
        var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("ChangePassword", new Type[] { typeof(ChangePasswordModel) });
        var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true);
        Assert.IsTrue(attributes.Any(), "No AuthorizeAttribute found on ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model) method");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan - I thought I might be testing at the wrong level. I'm happy with the idea of "assuming" that if the controller gets hit, the user is authenticated.

P.S. Are you sure it's tested in the framework? I can see a few tests supplying valid IPrincipal, but none that test the invalid case ;-)

Comment: Er, no... haven't actually verified that test case myself; I'm trusting the MVC gang to have got it right. My bad!

Comment: I like the answer for why it's not the right approach, but I am not convinced on the argument "the feature is tested in the framework and  works". I trust that the attribute is working properly, that's the job of the framework, but I would still like to assert which methods of my controllers use the attribute.

Comment: @Mathias - see edit for an example of how to use reflection to verify the presence of the required attributes.

Comment: @Dylan I tried you example in a MVC3 project and on the LogOn method although in my test I'm getting a "object reference not set to an instance of an object". I'm decorating the controller with the [Authorize] attribute. Thanks

Comment: Is this logic inverted? Also, this doesn't seem to cover when the attribute is applied to the controller.

Comment: `The [Authorize] attribute ensures that the routing engine will never invoke that method for an unauthorized user - the RedirectResult will actually be coming from the route, not from your controller method.` -
 Everything about this sentence is wrong. Routing happens long before authorization filters are run - [MVC Life Cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application). The `AuthorizeAttribute` (which is registered as an `IAuthorizationFilter`) supplies the `RedirectResult` when authorization fails.

Comment: I am trying to test my Web API custom attributes. This is a much simpler than creating an in-memory hosting HTTP server! Thanks @DylanBeattie!

Answer (score 28):

Well you might be testing at the wrong level but its the test that makes sense.  I mean, if I flag a method with the authorize(Roles="Superhero") attribute, I don't really need a test if I flagged it.  What I (think I) want is to test that an unauthorized user doesn't have access and that an authorized user does.

For a unauthorized user a test like this:

```
// Arrange
var user = SetupUser(isAuthenticated, roles);
var controller = SetupController(user);

// Act
SomeHelper.Invoke(controller => controller.MyAction());

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(401,
  controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode, "Status Code");
```

Well, it's not easy and it took me 10 hours, but here it is.  I hope someone can benefit from it or convince me to go into another profession.  :)  (BTW - I'm using rhino mock)

```
[Test]
public void AuthenticatedNotIsUserRole_Should_RedirectToLogin()
{
    // Arrange
    var mocks = new MockRepository();
    var controller = new FriendsController();
    var httpContext = FakeHttpContext(mocks, true);
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
    {
        Controller = controller,
        RequestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData())
    };

    httpContext.User.Expect(u => u.IsInRole("User")).Return(false);
    mocks.ReplayAll();

    // Act
    var result =
        controller.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(controller.ControllerContext, "Index");
    var statusCode = httpContext.Response.StatusCode;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(result, "Invoker Result");
    Assert.AreEqual(401, statusCode, "Status Code");
    mocks.VerifyAll();
}
```

Although, thats not very useful without this helper function:

```
public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext(MockRepository mocks, bool isAuthenticated)
{
    var context = mocks.StrictMock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = mocks.StrictMock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = mocks.StrictMock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var session = mocks.StrictMock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    var server = mocks.StrictMock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
    var cachePolicy = mocks.Stub<HttpCachePolicyBase>();
    var user = mocks.StrictMock<IPrincipal>();
    var identity = mocks.StrictMock<IIdentity>();
    var itemDictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();

    identity.Expect(id => id.IsAuthenticated).Return(isAuthenticated);
    user.Expect(u => u.Identity).Return(identity).Repeat.Any();

    context.Expect(c => c.User).PropertyBehavior();
    context.User = user;
    context.Expect(ctx => ctx.Items).Return(itemDictionary).Repeat.Any();
    context.Expect(ctx => ctx.Request).Return(request).Repeat.Any();
    context.Expect(ctx => ctx.Response).Return(response).Repeat.Any();
    context.Expect(ctx => ctx.Session).Return(session).Repeat.Any();
    context.Expect(ctx => ctx.Server).Return(server).Repeat.Any();

    response.Expect(r => r.Cache).Return(cachePolicy).Repeat.Any();
    response.Expect(r => r.StatusCode).PropertyBehavior();

    return context;
}
```

So that gets you confirmation that users not in a role don't have access.  I tried writing a test to confirm the opposite, but after two more hours of digging through mvc plumbing I will leave it to manual testers.  (I bailed when I got to the VirtualPathProviderViewEngine class.  WTF? I don't want anything to do a VirtualPath or a Provider or ViewEngine much the union of the three!)

I am curious as to why this is so hard in an allegedly "testable" framework.

Comment: WTF indeed, luckily if u stick to it u can find a way around it and around all following issues after it, just like I did. Take a loook at my github project at:
https://github.com/ibrahimbensalah/Xania.AspNet.Simulator/blob/master/Xania.AspNet.Simulator.Tests/

Comment: This post is _almost completely_ the same as the [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130213143434/http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/2009/05/23/aspnet-mvc-testing-a-custom-authorize-filters) refered in the post by @Dario. Did you develop this yourself?

Comment: Yes, it's developed all by myself, and still actively in development. currently supporting mvc4 and mvc5 from authorization, model binders, request validation, razor rendering....

Comment: This is an excellent answer @DanielEli! If you have any idea how to do it in .NET Core, I'd really appreciate it if you could have a look at my question here:https://stackoverflow.com/q/48562403/2664670

Comment: When I run the above example using Moq instead of Rhino Mocks, the StatusCode is always 0 in the Response. Does anyone have a working example using Moq?

Comment: @M.Mimpen Though since [Dario's link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/903093/1028230) is now deleted, copied or not, this answer now has more importance. (It looks like [you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1112472/m-mimpen) asked [Dario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77194/dario-quintana) to provide more info before his answer was deleted to give or take match what this answer does... Maybe you could combine the two answers with your additions in your comment to make your own uber answer?)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use reflection to look for the `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller class and / or the action method you are testing? Assuming the framework does make sure the Attribute is honored, this would be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: There are two distinct things being tested here. (1) Test that a custom attribute does what it's supposed to do; and (2) That a controller/action stays decorated with the attribute.  You're answering to (2) but I think the link posted by Dario Quintana best answers to (1).

Comment: In the real world, annotation with Authorize attribute is not the only way used to authorize requests / controller actions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree with Dylan's answer, because 'user must be logged in' does not imply that 'controller method is annotated with AuthorizeAttribute'

to ensure 'user must be logged in' when you call the action method, the ASP.NET MVC framework does something like this (just hold on, it will get simpler eventually)

```
let $filters = All associated filter attributes which implement
               IAuthorizationFilter

let $invoker = instance of type ControllerActionInvoker
let $ctrlCtx = instance or mock of type ControllerContext
let $actionDesc = instance or mock of type ActionDescriptor
let $authzCtx = $invoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters($ctrlCtx, $filters, $actionDesc);

then controller action is authorized when $authzCtx.Result is not null
```

It is hard to implement this pseudo script in a working c# code. Likely, [Xania.AspNet.Simulator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xania.AspNet.Simulator/) makes it really simple to setup a test like this and performs exactly these step under the cover. here is an example.

first install the package from nuget (version 1.4.0-beta4 at the time of writing)

> PM > install-package Xania.AspNet.Simulator -Pre

Then your test method could look like this (assuming NUnit and FluentAssertions are installed):

```
[Test]
public void AnonymousUserIsNotAuthorized()
{
  // arrange
  var action = new ProfileController().Action(c => c.Index());
  // act
  var result = action.GetAuthorizationResult();
  // assert
  result.Should().NotBeNull(); 
}

[Test]
public void LoggedInUserIsAuthorized()
{
  // arrange
  var action = new ProfileController().Action(c => c.Index())
     // simulate authenticated user
     .Authenticate("user1", new []{"role1"});
  // act
  var result = action.GetAuthorizationResult();
  // assert
  result.Should().BeNull(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For .NET Framework we use this class to verify that every MVC and API Controller have `AuthorizeAttribute` and that every API Controller should have a `RoutePrefixAttribute`.

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestControllerHasAuthorizeRole
{
    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetChildTypes<T>()
    {
        var types = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetTypes();
        return types.Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)) && !t.IsAbstract);
    }

    [Test]
    public void MvcControllersShouldHaveAuthrorizeAttribute()
    {
        var controllers = GetChildTypes<Controller>();
        foreach (var controller in controllers)
        {
            var authorizeAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(controller, typeof(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute), true) as System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute;
            Assert.IsNotNull(authorizeAttribute, $"MVC-controller {controller.FullName} does not implement AuthorizeAttribute");
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void ApiControllersShouldHaveAuthorizeAttribute()
    {
        var controllers = GetChildTypes<ApiController>();
        foreach (var controller in controllers)
        {
            var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(controller, typeof(System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute), true) as System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute;
            Assert.IsNotNull(attribute, $"API-controller {controller.FullName} does not implement AuthorizeAttribute");
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void ApiControllersShouldHaveRoutePrefixAttribute()
    {
        var controllers = GetChildTypes<ApiController>();
        foreach (var controller in controllers)
        {
            var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(controller, typeof(System.Web.Http.RoutePrefixAttribute), true) as System.Web.Http.RoutePrefixAttribute;
            Assert.IsNotNull(attribute, $"API-controller {controller.FullName} does not implement RoutePrefixAttribute");
            Assert.IsTrue(attribute.Prefix.StartsWith("api/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), $"API-controller {controller.FullName} does not have a route prefix that starts with api/");
        }
    }
}
```

It is a bit easier in .NET Core and .NET 5<. Here a MVC Controller inherits from `Controller` that in turn inherits from `ControllerBase`. An Api Controller inherits directly from `ControllerBase` and therefore we can test MVC and API Controllers using a single method:

```
public class AuthorizeAttributeTest
{
    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetChildTypes<T>()
    {
        var types = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetTypes();
        return types.Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)) && !t.IsAbstract);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ApiAndMVCControllersShouldHaveAuthorizeAttribute()
    {
        var controllers = GetChildTypes<ControllerBase>();
        foreach (var controller in controllers)
        {
            var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(controller, typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute), true) as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute;
            Assert.NotNull(attribute);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is a great code snippet. Thanks for sharing... even on a question that was 12 years old when you answered it :D

Comment: @C.Tewalt Haha thx! :D