# HttpClient.GetAsync cannot access policy protected api endpoint

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core

I am writing unit test for controllers in an asp.net core web application, it uses Identity framework for authentication. I was able to create an authenticated `HttpClient` with valid bearer token. But when the client tried to `GetAsync` from an endpoint that is policy protected (e.g. `RequireRole("Admin")`), it always fails with error 500, but if I make that endpoint `[AllowAnonymous]`, it will work. I've tried using `SignInManager` to sign in first, thinking that will provide the context user, still the same. So, how to use `GetAsync` to access a policy protected endpoint in unit test?

Comment: Hi @for-comment, you need `integration test` for this. Because this attribute processes the request pipeline by framework and you could not test it with `unit tests`. You need to start up your service `new TestServer(...)` in memory and test it. Please, check this [answear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562403/unit-testing-an-authorizeattribute-on-an-asp-net-core-mvc-api-controller). And we can close it like *duplication*

Comment: this is part of the integration tests, it is generating the in-memory server with `WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient()`, which generates the authenticated client, also the auto generated test DB already contains the test user's credential that has the admin role.