# .net Core 3.1 unit test authorization roles on controller level

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-3.1, authorize-attribute

I have controllers with role based Authorize attribute, below is an example. I want to test authorization role setting for each controller, for example only "company admin", "group admin" can access UserController. what is the best way to do it?

```
    [Authorize(Roles = ("company admin", "group admin")]
    [Route("api/v1/")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerWithLog
    {
```

thanks!

Comment: Hi, first this is will be not a unit testing this will be integration functional testing! to test authorization you need to bring up in your test all infrastructure! and make a http request with specific token

Comment: Check up this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562403/unit-testing-an-authorizeattribute-on-an-asp-net-core-mvc-api-controller and this https://medium.com/asos-techblog/testing-authorization-scenarios-in-asp-net-core-web-api-484bc95d5f6f

Comment: I have this integration tests in place, with claim set up for each request. However, I tried to find a way to test Authorize roles setting for its own, rather than testing accessibility for each endpoint with different roles.  It is just like you would put [Authorize(Roles = ("company admin", "group admin")] on controller level, rather than on each route level.

Comment: If you just want to make sure that on your controller or API method there is Authorize attribute with specific parameters I would use the reflection and will scan all the controllers and obtain the custom attributes and check if it correct role is assigned and that's it!

Comment: thanks, that is one of the options I thought about, but am wondering if there is other way to test it